# RSpec2: view.should render_template best practices?

Tags: rspec, rspec2

I've been looking for the definitive answer for months now, and the
RSpec book doesn't touch on it at all:

**How do we now handle stubbing out rendering of partials in view specs
in RSpec2?**

I have a large (35K+ lines of views and related specs) that I'm trying
to upgrade to Rails3/RSpec2. My views use partials pretty extensively
and this issue is a huge blocker for me.

```
before do
 view.should render_template("event_list", :locals => {:calendar => @calendar})
end
```

causes all my related specs fail with:

```
expecting <"event_list"> but rendering with <"">.
Expected block to return true value.
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I think you now need to pass in a hash instead of the name of the partial:

```
view.should render_template(:partial=>"_event_list", :locals => {:calendar => @calendar})
```

**EDIT**

FWIW I couldn't make [this](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/#issue/263/comment/547999) work either, but monkeypatching made it pass:

```
class ActionView::Base
  def stub_partial(hash)
    view_paths.unshift(ActionView::FixtureResolver.new(hash))
  end
end
```

then

```
before(:each) do
  view.stub_partial("path_to/_partial" => "")
end
```

Maybe David will explain the right way to do it ...

Comment: Unfortunately, that blows up Rspec with:You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]

Comment: Hmm. I tried this earlier and it worked. Are you calling `render` before `view.should`

Comment: I need to do this via a before block, as the rendering of the partial happens on every spec. It looks like David knows its an issue: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/#issue/263

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood what you were trying to do. Does the edited answer work?

Comment: Unfortunately, the edited code doesn't work either. The spec goes on to render the partial in every spec. WTH? It doesn't seem like this would be so hard :|